# Get only installed apps' .deb files from debian repository to cache for offline installation including dependencies

Tags: debian, apt, backup, dependencies

I generally have bad internet connection and it makes trouble when `apt-get install an-app`. So I am backing up .deb files in `/var/cache/apt/archives` regularly and copying into the same folder when I do new installation. This way, dependencies of applications with the exception of already installed ones are also backing up. And I found this command to download **all**  dependencies of an app including the ones that already installed on my system:

```
apt-get download $(apt-cache depends --recurse --no-recommends --no-suggests --no-conflicts --no-breaks --no-replaces --no-pre-depends <appname> | grep "^\w" | sort -u)
apt-get download <appname>
```

I use this because some dependencies of app may not be installed on a new system.

But in this condition if I upgrade any application, I also store its old .deb file on my disk. And these files becomes garbage. I need to clean this garbage from cache folder. So my question is:

Is there any way of mirroring the repository files for only specific applications and its all dependencies (and only latest versions)?
Or
mirror the debian repository for specific apps only using `apt-mirror` or something similar?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Finally I resolved with these steps:

1. Make backup of `/var/cache/apt` directory (not only `/var/cache/apt/archives`).
2. set `APT::Clean-Installed` property to `false` in `apt.conf` file.
   to do this make a .conf file in `/etc/apt/apt.conf.d` and add
   `APT::Clean-Installed "false";` line. For example:

   ```
   $ sudo touch /etc/apt/apt.conf.d/custom.conf
   $ sudo echo "APT::Clean-Installed "false";" > /etc/apt/apt.conf.d/custom.conf
   ```
3. To clean cache without installed apps' files:

   ```
   $ sudo apt-get autoclean
   ```

I got this from `man 8 apt-get`:

> autoclean (and the auto-clean alias since 1.1) 
>              Like clean, autoclean clears out the local repository of retrieved
>              package files. The difference is that it only removes package files
>              that can no longer be downloaded, and are largely useless. This
>              allows a cache to be maintained over a long period without it
>              growing out of control. The configuration option
>              APT::Clean-Installed will prevent installed packages from being
>              erased if it is set to off.